# linux - sync two local directories

Tags: linux, synchronization, local, rsync, directory

I need to sync two local directories in linux.
For example **/var/www** and **/www**.
I heard about Rsync but I don't know how to use it.
Basically, when I put something in **/var/www** it needs to appear in **/www** and when I put something in **/www** it needs to appear in **/var/www**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not make a soft link of the two files, then when you load something into one directory it loads it into the other.

```
ln -s {target-filename} {symbolic-filename}
ln -s /var/www /www
```